# Intellij inspection for switch case fall-through

Tags: java, intellij-idea, switch-statement

Does Intellij IDEA have an inspection for a possibly unintentional fall-through in a `switch` statement due to a forgotten `break`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does:

[image: switch]

> Reports 'fall-through' in a switch statement. Fall-through is defined
>   to occur when a series of executable statements after a switch label
>   is not guaranteed to transfer control before the next switch label. In
>   that case, control falls through to the statements after that switch
>   label, even though the switch expression does not equal the value of
>   the fallen-through label. While occasionally intended, this
>   construction is confusing, and is often the result of a typo.

Note that this inspection is disabled by default, so tick a checkbox on the right if you want to use it.